# How to insert Components to a JTextPane, one from left and Other from right

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am working on a chat application where I am using a JTextPane to display the conversation, I want to insert the senders's message to the left and the receiver's message to the right of JTextPane, I am wrapping the text inside another JTextPane which looks like a balloon. I am able to insert the message only to the left but not to the right!!! any suggestion will be helpful and appreciated. You can get the Idea from the Image provided.
Thanks

Note: this question is not duplicate, it is related to components not text alignment or gravity!

[image]

Comment: Get a good layout manager .

Comment: @joeyrohan: shoot a BoxLayout for the inner JPanel would be the main thing that would be needed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would prefer `CSS` than anything else in this case or in any case :)

Answer (score 5):

Do not use JTextPane (as underlaying component) to add further components.
This may not work as you expect.

To achieve that, i would use JPanel with custom layout-manager which arranges the messages (which could be JLabels) like you want.
Custom-Layout could be some kind of TableLayout with 2 columns and n-Rows

EDIT:
Here is a link to box layout example.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box
or even better http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html
Each row can be a JLabel, with different alignment (for example)

Comment: Few links can be helpful for the OP :)